# Implementing Multiple Elif for Multiple Choice of Color Converter cause "Future Warning"

Tags: python, image, tkinter, opencv

Everyone. I have a question about implementing list of multiple choice for Color Converter selection in Python.
Here the code

List of Option

```
effectoption = ["Effect RGB",
                "Effect HSV",
                "Effect LAB",
                "Effect RGBA",
                "Effect HLS"]
```

If Else

```
if effect == effectoption[0] :
    edited = cv2.cvtColor(edited, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
elif effect == effectoption[1] :
    edited = cv2.cvtColor(edited, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
elif effect == effectoption[2] :
    edited = cv2.cvtColor(edited, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
elif effect == effectoption[3] :
    edited = cv2.cvtColor(edited, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
elif effect == effectoption[4] :
    edited = cv2.cvtColor(edited, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
```

The current code is

```
#image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
on_change(image) #the code will print none and this code was supposed for get value of effect option for applying image
```

The setting of Color Converter is here

```
opt = tk.OptionMenu(window, var1, *effectoption)
opt.config(width=90, font=('Helvetica', 12))
opt.pack(side="top")
```

And here's the full code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image as PILImage
from PIL import ImageTk
from tkinter import Label
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Menu
import cv2
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
 
WINDOW_NAME = "CV2 Photo Editor"

"""
effectoption = ["Effect RGB",
                "Effect HSV",
                "Effect LAB",
                "Effect RGBA",
                "Effect HLS", "Effect GRAY"]
"""
effectoption = [("Effect RGB"),
                ("Effect HSV"),
                ("Effect LAB"),
                ("Effect RGBA"),
                ("Effect HLS"), ("Effect GRAY")]

 
effectoption2 = ["Original(RGB)",
                 "Original(HSV)",
                 "Effect3"]
 
def on_change(effect):
    if effect == effectoption[0]:
        edited = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        var1.set(effectoption[0])
        print(var1.get())
    if effect == effectoption[1]:
        edited = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        var1.set(effectoption[1])
        print(var1.get())
    if effect == effectoption[2]:
        edited = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
        var1.set(effectoption[2])
        print(var1.get())
    if effect == effectoption[3]:
        edited = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        var1.set(effectoption[3])
        print(var1.get())
    if effect == effectoption[4]:
        edited = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
        var1.set(effectoption[4])
        print(var1.get())
    if effect == effectoption[5]:
        edited = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        var1.set(effectoption[5])
        print(var1.get())
    else :
        edited = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    print(effect)
    #print(edited)
def insertbutton_cb():
    #global orima, editima
    global image, edited
 
    picpath = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        title="Select An Image",
        filetypes=(("JPG Files", "*.jpg"), ("GIF Files", "*.gif*"), ("PNG files", "*.png"), ("JPEG Files", "*.jpeg"))
    )
 
    if len(picpath) > 0:
        
        bright = 255
        contrast = 100
        saturation = 50
        
 
        image = cv2.imread(picpath)
        edited = cv2.imread(picpath)
 
        edited = np.array(edited)
        #edited = PILImage.fromarray(edited.astype('uint8'))
 
        print(picpath)
        print('Original Dimensions : ',image.shape)
        print(image)
        print(edited)
 
        scale_percent = 50 # percent of original size
        width = int(image.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
        height = int(image.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
        width2 = int(edited.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
        height2 = int(edited.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
        dim = (width, height)
        dim2 = (width2, height2)
 
        image = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        edited = cv2.resize(edited, dim2, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
 
        #if effectoption[0] :
            #edited = cv2.cvtColor(edited, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        #elif effectoption[1] :
            #edited = cv2.cvtColor(edited, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        #elif effectoption[2] :
            #edited = cv2.cvtColor(edited, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
        #elif effectoption[3] :
            #edited = cv2.cvtColor(edited, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        #elif effectoption[4] :
            #edited = cv2.cvtColor(edited, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
 
        #image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        #on_change(image)
        print(on_change(image))
        #edited = cv2.cvtColor(edited, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
 
        image =  PILImage.fromarray(image)
        edited = PILImage.fromarray(edited)
 
        #xa, ya, za = np.shape(image)
        #xb, yb, zb = np.shape(edited)
 
        #image = np.ones((xa, ya, za), np.uint8)
        #edited = np.ones((xb, yb, zb), np.uint8)
 
        image = np.uint8(image)
        edited = np.uint8(edited)
 
        #hueSlider = tk.Scale(Frm2, label="Hue",from_=0, to=100, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=sw, resolution=1, command=huecb)
        #hueSlider.pack(anchor=tk.N)
 
        #saturationSlider = tk.Scale(Frm2, label="Saturation",from_=0, to=100, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=sw, resolution=1, command=satcb)
        #saturationSlider.pack(anchor=tk.N)
 
        #brightSlider = tk.Scale(Frm2, label="Brightness",from_=0, to=100, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=sw, resolution=1, command=brightcb)
        #brightSlider.pack(anchor=tk.N)
 
        #contrastSlider = tk.Scale(Frm2, label="Contrast",from_=0, to=100, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=sw, resolution=1, command=contrastcb)
        #contrastSlider.pack(anchor=tk.N)

        #create trackbars for high,low H,S,V 
 
        cv2.namedWindow(WINDOW_NAME)
        cv2.createTrackbar('Bright', WINDOW_NAME, 255, 2 * 255, bccb)
        cv2.createTrackbar('Contrast', WINDOW_NAME, 255, 2 * 127, bccb)
        cv2.createTrackbar('Saturation', WINDOW_NAME, 255, 2 * 255, bccb)
        #functionbcs(edited, 0, 0, 0)
        bccb(0, 0, 0)
        teste = controller(image, bright, contrast, saturation)
        cv2.imshow(WINDOW_NAME, teste)
 
        #cv2.waitKey(0)
    """
    if orima is None or editima is None:
        orima = Label(image=image)
        orima.image = image
        orima.pack(side="left", padx= 0, pady=0)
 
        editima = Label(image=edited)
        editima.image = edited
        editima.pack(side="right", padx= 0, pady=0)
    else:
        orima.configure(image=image)
        editima.configure(image=edited)
        orima.image = image
        editima.image = edited
    """
 
def resetbutton_cb():
    """
    orima = None
    editima = None
    """
    pass
 
def savebutton_cb():
    pass
 
"""
def functionbcs(edited, bright=0, contrast=0, saturation=0):
 
    #edited = cv2.cvtColor(edited, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    bright = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Bright','CV2 Photo Editor')
    contrast = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Contrast','CV2 Photo Editor')
    saturation = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Saturation','CV2 Photo Editor')
    edited = controller(edited, bright, contrast, saturation)
    #print("Edited : " + edited)
    print(edited)
    cv2.imshow("Edited", edited)
 
def satcb(satpos = 0):
    print(satpos)
"""
 
def bccb(bright = 0, contrast=0, saturation=0):
    bright = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Bright', WINDOW_NAME)
    print("B : " + str(bright))
    contrast = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Contrast', WINDOW_NAME)
    print("C : " + str(contrast))
    saturation = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Saturation', WINDOW_NAME)
    print("S : " + str(saturation))
 
    edited = controller(image, bright, contrast, saturation)
    cv2.imshow(WINDOW_NAME, edited)
 
def controller(effect, bright=1, contrast=1, saturation=1):
    bright = int((bright - 0) * (255 - (-255)) / (510 - 0) + (-255))
 
    contrast = int((contrast - 0) * (127 - (-127)) / (254 - 0) + (-127))
 
    saturation = int((saturation - 0) * (100 - (-100)) / (200 - 0) + (-100))
 
    if bright != 0:
        if bright > 0:
            shadow = bright
            max = 255
        else:
            shadow = 0
            max = 255 + bright
        alf = (max - shadow) / 255
        gam = shadow
 
        cal = cv2.addWeighted(effect, alf,
                              effect, 0, gam) # changed edited to effect, alfa to alf
    else:
        cal = effect
 
    if contrast != 0:
        Alf2 = float(131 * (contrast + 127)) / (127 * (131 - contrast))
        Gam2 = 127 * (1 - Alf2)
 
        # The function addWeighted calculates
        # the weighted sum of two arrays
        cal = cv2.addWeighted(cal, Alf2,
                              cal, 0, Gam2)
    #cv2.imshow('CV2 Photo Editor', effect)
 
    return cal
 
 
def exitbutton_cb():
    window.destroy()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
 
 
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Simple Photo Editing')
mb = Menu(window)
#file manager
fm = Menu(mb, tearoff=0)
fm.add_command(label="Open", command=insertbutton_cb)
fm.add_command(label="Save", command=savebutton_cb)
fm.add_separator()
#fm.add_command(label="Cancel Edit", command=pass)
fm.add_command(label="Exit", command=exitbutton_cb)
mb.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fm)
 
var1 = tk.StringVar(window)
var1.set(effectoption[0])
var1.get()
 
cr = ttk.Frame(window)
canvas = tk.Canvas(cr)
scrolling = ttk.Scrollbar(cr, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
 
sw = window.winfo_screenwidth()
sh = window.winfo_screenheight()
 
Frm = tk.Frame(window, height=50, width=300)
Frm.pack(anchor=tk.N)
 
Frm2 = tk.Frame(window, height=25, width=100)
Frm2.pack(anchor=tk.NW)
 
#Frm3 = tk.Frame(window, height=50, width=500)
#Frm3.pack(anchor=tk.N)
 
#showWin = tk.Label(window, width=100, height=100)
#showWin.pack(side='left')
 
#showWin2 = tk.Label(window, width=100, height=100)
#showWin2.pack(side='left')
 
label = ttk.Label(
    window, text="Simple Image Photo Editing"
)
 
resetbutton = tk.Button(Frm, text="Reset", padx=0, pady=0, command=resetbutton_cb)
resetbutton.grid(row=0, column=1)
 
savebutton = tk.Button(Frm, text="Save", padx=0, pady=0, command=savebutton_cb)
savebutton.grid(row=0, column=2)
 
orima = None
editima = None
 
opt = tk.OptionMenu(window, var1, *effectoption, command=on_change)
opt.config(width=90, font=('Helvetica', 12))
opt.pack(side="top")
 
print(opt)
print(var1)
print(var1.get())
 
window.config(menu=mb)
cv2.waitKey(0)
tk.mainloop()
```

The Question is how to implement correctly for selecting one choice replacing "if elif"(multiple if elif cause "elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison"?

Comment: Attempting to edit down your question is recommended. Looks like your comparison is a little silly though, you will always match the first `if x`, you probably meant `if x == y`

Comment: I already change the code by adding few words

Comment: What's the type of `effect`? From the error message I would guess that   it's not a string but something else

Comment: effect is cv2 image which from def insertbutton callback which is image = cv2.imread(picpath)

Answer (score 0):

This is hardly Minimal Reproducible example. When you do `effect == effectoption[0]`, the right side is a string, so the left side has to be a string as well. If `effect` is a list that contains a string, then you need to take the element that's a string. Also, your `on_change` function can probably be simplified quite a bit, such as perhaps

```
def on_change(effect):
    effect_choice = getattr(cv2, "COLOR_BGR2"+effect.split()[1])
    edited = cv2.cvtColor(image, effect_choice)
    var1.set(effect)
    print(var1.get())
    print(effect)
```

Generally speaking, if you find yourself using `elif`, you should consider whether there's a simpler way of doing it.

Comment: when I run the code f on_change(effect), def on_change(effect) error because 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split' (effect is cv2)

Comment: @DeanPrananda Yes, it's the same problem: `effect` is not a string. You need to extract the string you want from `effect`.